# Pokemon sun aether paradise

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I'm stuck in aether paradise in pokemon sun,
when Fabio asked me if I finished visiting I accidentally said yes and now I don't know where to go. Is it possible to go back to a save file before I said yes or delete some files? Or is there another way to carry on in the game after I said yes?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean you defeated Faba and are now talking to Gladion. If this is incorrect, please clarify your question as it's quite vague

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague. If you've just accessed the lower levels after your first encounter with Faba:

From [this walkthrough:](https://bulbahandbook.bulbagarden.net/pokemonsunmoon/walkthrough/alola-aether-paradise-revisit)

> After you have defeated him, Faba will grant you access to the lower
> floors. When Gladion asks you if you’re ready to go, reply with “no”.
> Head south until you find the friendly Aether Foundation Employee who
> offers to heal your Pokémon. Now head back and travel down to the
> lower labs with Gladion.

You are unable to go back until you have cleared the lower level section. Continue forward.

If instead you are referring to the second Faba encounter, near the end of Aether Paradise:

> Guzma and Lusamine make a swift exit after the battle so you can relax
> for a bit now. Leave the mansion and Lillie will be waiting outside
> for you. Gladion hands Lillie a Moon Flute (Pokémon Sun) / Sun Flute
> (Pokémon Moon). He also hands you a Master Ball.
>
> There’s not much more to do on Aether Paradise right now so it’s about
> time that you head over to Poni Island. Simply retrace your steps by
> heading south, taking the elevator down to B1F: Docks and speak to
> Gladion.

[Additional source](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Aether_Paradise#Pok.C3.A9mon_Sun_and_Moon) (spoilers)